# How to Use Timeout Correctly for QTimer in Flashing Labels?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtimer

I am trying to create a code where I flash two labels (with images in them) continuously.  I am using QTimer to help create the blinking/flashing however I am unfamiliar with using this before.  I get the error message "TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable" for

```
blink = blinkTimer.timeout()
```

From my research on this I've seen something about slots... I don't know if that is where my problem is?  And if it is, an explanation of slots for using timeout would be super helpful and appreciated!

Here is my working code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from testBlinking import *
from testBlinking import Ui_MainWindow

QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui: Ui_MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)

ui.label_2.hide()

blinkTimer = QTimer()
blink = blinkTimer.timeout()

def onblink():
        if  ui.label.show():
            ui.label.hide()
            ui.label_2.show()
        else:
            ui.label.show()
            ui.label_2.hide()

blink.connect(onblink)
blink.start(500)
```

Here is the updated code right edited after the suggestions below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from testBlinking import *
from testBlinking import Ui_MainWindow

QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)

ui.label.hide()
ui.label_2.hide()

blinkTimer = QTimer()

def onblink():
        if ui.label.show():
            ui.label.hide()
            ui.label_2.show()
        else:
            ui.label.show()
            ui.label_2.hide()
blinkTimer.timeout.connect(onblink)
blinkTimer.start(500)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Currently only the first label shows but it does not blink.  In my python code, the connect from `blinkTimer.timeout.connect(onblink)` is highlighted... could it be that it is not connecting my function for some reason?

Comment: 1. remove `blink = blinkTimer.timeout()`

Comment: 2. change `blink.connect(onblink)` to `blinkTimer.timeout.connect(onblink)`

Comment: 3. change `blink.start(500)` to `blinkTimer.start(500)`

Comment: I did as you said and the program ran without any errors however it is only showing the first label and not blinking... I think this may be something with my function or the .connect because in my python code ```blinkTimer.timeout.connect(onblink)``` the connect is highlighted.  Any suggestions on that?

Comment: add `sys.exit(app.exec_())` after `blinkTimer.start(500)`

Comment: I have window.show() and sys.exit(app.exec_()) after that already

Comment: In what part of the code do you show what you point out? I do not see it. Is your code an [MCVE] as required in SO?

Comment: Woops, I'm sorry! I thought I had that as part of the code I shared in my original question but I see that it is not there.  I edited the original post to include the updated code that I have right now and the current problem (with the connect)

Comment: provide a **[MCVE]**